# List Decorated functions within Object

Tags: python, oop, module, decorator

This is not the actual thing I'm doing but a similar scenario.

I want to store a list of functions that have a certain decorator under the `self.funcs` variable.

```py
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func = []

    ### Wrapper Function Here
    

cal = Calculator()

@<wrapper>
def add_function(no1,no2):
    return no1+no2

print([i.__name__ for i in cal.funcs])
# Shows Functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly but I think you mean this
eg

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.funcs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
@foo
def a():
    return None
@bar 
def b():
    return None

@car
def c():
    return None

@bar
def d():
    return None
```

Now assuming you have the list of wrappers you want.

```py
desired_wrapper_to_search_for = [bar]
f = Foo()
method_names = f.funcs
your_result = []

for method in method_names:
    for gwrapper in desired_wrapper_to_search_for:
        if str(gwrapper.__code__.co_consts[2]) in str(eval(method)):
            your_result.append(method)
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: No. The function is created and decorated outside the class.
The list of functions decorated is stored inside the class/instance variable

Comment: @FishballNooodles I edited is this what you wanted?